# Problems with importing a python library

Tags: python

Currently I'm trying to use this python library:

https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/blob/master/armoryd.py

Essentially, I'm able to run:

```
python armoryd armory_2BEfTgvpofds_.watchonly.wallet
```

Only when I pass a .wallet argument.

I want to do the same with a script that I create. But when I import the library, it's asking for a wallet argument. When I do something like:

```
import armoryd armory_2BEfTgvpofds_.watchonly.wallet
```

It is complaining about an invalid syntax.

Is it possible to import this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from armoryd import armory_2BEfTgvpofds_.watchonly.wallet
```

Your import statement is invalid, it needs to be `from MODULE import SOMETHING1, SOMETHING2...etc`

Also you need to ensure that your armoryd library is on the *PYTHONPATH*

### update

https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/blob/master/extras/sample_armory_code.py

take a look there - a sample on how to use the armory code in python.

Comment: That also produces a syntax error. I'm getting a syntax error with ^ pointed below the first '.' of the wallet file.

Comment: is it telling you that there is no module?

Comment: No it isn't. If I try importing it without the wallet path: IE just import armoryd, it complains that there is no wallet path.

Comment: I'm guessing that the '.' character is causing problems and maybe they can be escaped?

Comment: The link that you provided is for the armoryengine.py library and not armoryd.py. armoryd.py uses armoryengine and has some specific functions that I wanted to take advantage of. I don't have any problems with import armoryengine, but I do with this one.

Comment: You would need to cut that file apart and cherry pick out what you want, armoryd is meant to run as a deamon and so it is not designed to be used/imported straight out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for this library, you won't be able to import it in such a way.  It is hard coded to take parameters from the command line.

```
if len(CLI_ARGS)==0:
         LOGERROR('Please supply the wallet for this server to serve')
         LOGERROR('USAGE:  %s [--testnet] [--whatever] file.wallet' % sys.argv[0])
         os._exit(1)
```

As Mike McMahon mentioned, there is a way to import the code, but you won't be able to import armoryd.

https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/blob/master/extras/sample_armory_code.py